# how to prevent overlapping on a (hover) scaled (with transform) image with css?

Tags: css

I have mini images of products which I want to zoom on hover without changing any position. I was able to do that but I have this issue.

[image]

after hovering this image it scales as expected.

[image]

but I was not able to prevent the overlap. I tried a high z-index but it didn't work. This is the css.

```
.minipic {
    transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    height: 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.zoom {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.zoom:hover > .minipic{
    z-index: 99999;
    transition: all .3s ease-out .25s;
    transform: translate(-0px,-0px) scale(5);
}
```

ps: I dont think that it matters but I am using quasar

Comment: Try to add a position: relative with the z-index ?

Comment: @ThéoBenoit you were right it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the next thing.
I would personally put the img inside an `a` tag and therefore do this next tweak. I have used it in a website in which I am working and it totally should work.

CSS would be like:

```
a.minipic {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all .3s ease-out 0s;
    height: 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
a.minipic:hover> img {
    min-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

a.minipic > img {
    min-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateX(-40px);
}
```

HTML would be like this

```
 <a class="minipic">
      <img src="../img/yourimg.png" class="img-responsive">
 </a>
```